# angular project on production mode in vercel cors problem

Tags: angular, cors, vercel

i develop a angular project, this project angular version is 11.0.2. When develop project on my local, i define a proxy.config.json and it is run without any cors problem.

When i decide publish project, deploy to vercel but http client requests return cors error. My vercel.json config file is

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I learn proxy.conf.json file not work on production mode and. i updated all service requests api endpoint url to real string url.

I test all api endpoints on postman, backend is work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem this with this vercel.json config file

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/api/:match*", "destination": "https://api.endpoint.url/:match*" }

  ],
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

my all http client requests like this

```
this.http.post<Response>(`api/${service}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you have to configure something in the angular.json?
of the type

```
      "configurations": {
        "product": {
          "buildTarget": "App:build:prod",
          "proxyConfig": "./proxy.prod.json" <== instead of this did you put vercel.json??
        }
```

ok it worked, just put the vercel.json in the path I specified above and write the vercel.json correctly and it works